# msbuild version

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

**Error :**

> error : Version 6.0.404 of the .NET SDK requires at least version
> 17.0.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 16.11.2.50704. Change the .NET SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.

How can I update my msbuild version I have only:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0
```

My Visual studio version is 2019

Comment: A typical install location for msbuild is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe.  Be sure to use the Developer Command Prompt.

Comment: Does the answer work for your question? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help in here. If it works you can consider accepting it, it will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2019 for Windows doesn't support .NET 6. You need VS2022 for MSBuild v17 and .NET 6 support.

You can upgrade to VS2022 or install VS2022 side-by-side with VS2019. You can install any of the VS2022 installation variants: 'Community', 'Professional', 'Enterprise', or 'Build Tools'. There is not an installer for MSBuild by itself.

The `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0` path is not where you are using MSBuild from. The error message notes you are using version 16.11.2.50704. Open a `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019` and run `where msbuild`, if you are curious about the actual location.

Comment: This helped me being stuck in a loop of not being able to load my .NET 7.0 web project. I kept seeing "Version 7.0.101 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.3.0 of MSBuild" and didn't twig that it was because my home laptop was using VS 2019. Opened the project in 2022 and lo and behold it worked. 

FYI before this message, I was getting the NETSDK1045 error "The current .NET SDK does not support 'newer version' as a target.", with the newer version being .NET 7.0. I deleted my older dotnet versions and that exposed this error message.

Comment: Great tip - thanks! I'd ported a project to a new PC and got this error in VS2019, which is what I'd been using on the old PC. I simply opened the project in VS2022, and it went away. You've saved me a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

Run from cmd to get the version:

```
   msbuild/version
```